# How can I set PrivateBinPath in MEF?

Tags: dll, plugins, mef

How can I set PrivateBinPath in MEF?

This is what I'm trying to do : [How to change the loading path of references in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806383/how-to-change-the-loading-path-of-references-in-net)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this through application config file: [assemblyBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twy1dw1e.aspx) element, more precisely - [probing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx):

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This will force runtime to look for assemblies in `bin`, `bin2`, `bin2\subbin` and `bin3` directories, all of which are subdirectories of the application's base directory.

Comment: Thanks for that, been tearing my hair out with this!