# how to change the location that the references dlls are copied to?

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, reference

i am using some libraries and i added a reference to that library dll and i set the "Copy Local" to true.
but i want to change the location of the dll to be a subfolder in the exe folder and not  with the exe.
how is this possible?
thanks

Update:
i used the following Post-build event [as Jon Skeet recommended]

```
move /y $(TargetDir)\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll   $(TargetDir)\Lib\SqlSrvCe\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a .config file for your .exe so that the probing path is changed.  A subdirectory is no problem, just use the `<probing>` element, its privatePath attribute is a relative folder name.

Beware however that you'll get little help from the IDE to put the DLL in that spot.  You'll need a post build event that creates the folder if necessary and xcopy's the DLL there.  Something like this:

```
if not exist "$(TargetDir)mumble" mkdir "$(TargetDir)mumble"
xcopy /d /y "$(TargetDir)something.dll" "$(TargetDir)mumble"
```

Comment: this link contains the xml to put inside app.config for the probing path to work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806467/how-can-i-set-privatebinpath-in-mef

Comment: If anyone is having problems with this, it could be because there are spaces in your path. So surround them with quotes: "$(TargetDir)mumble"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it's feasible within "normal" build rules, but you could add post-build steps which basically moved the files. It would be ugly, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it as a reference? Or is the reference only to copy the dll to the desired location?

If you do not need the reference, try adding it to the project and setting it to always copy.

[Add the dll to a folder in the project and set to Copy to Output Directory http://web11.twitpic.com/img/146848312-ecfdeadf5b322fe755c7a764d6e6dbf0.4c69c2f0-full.png](http://web11.twitpic.com/img/146848312-ecfdeadf5b322fe755c7a764d6e6dbf0.4c69c2f0-full.png)