# Create and Copy files in post-build event

Tags: visual-studio-2010, post-build-event, post-build

I have several build configurations and depending on the configuration chosen, I need to copy the `dll` to a `created folder`.  Basically, my executable is located on `c:\project` and my `dll` is in `c:\library`.  I need to setup a `post-build`event on the `dll` so that it creates a folder called `custom` in the `c:\project` executable directory and then copy the `dll` to this `custom folder`.  How do I accomplish the above?  One thing I have noticed is that a post-build event on the `dll` does not give me access to the executables directory and I don't want to have to hard code something like `c:\project\bin\debug` for example.

Comment: You need to ask a question.

Comment: It seems that just creating a batch file that is called from the post-build event could do that.  Or is there some complexity involved that prevents this from working?

Comment: @HansPassant - My question is I am not sure how to do it?  Updated anyways.

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497989/how-to-change-the-location-that-the-references-dlls-are-copied-to/3498184#3498184

Comment: @HansPassant - In your example, is that post-build event on the executable target path?

Comment: $(TargetDir) is a macro for the target directory.

Comment: @HansPassant - But  I need to copy from one target directory to another?  The dll I need to copy is not in the bin folder of the executbale.

Comment: A project has only one target directory.  It cannot guess where the file is supposed to come from, you'll need to help.  This is otherwise solved by having the projects in a solution, the build results go into the solution folder.