# MEF can load an assembly but doesn't load any parts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, plugins, mef, mvccontrib

I'm building a plugin framework using MvcContrib's portable areas and MEF to allow adding portable areas as plugins without needing to recompile (just drop your dll in the bin/Modules folder) or have a direct reference to the plugin project.

While developing the plugin I have a solution with two projects: MyFramework and MyPlugin.  Everything works just fine.  I have another solution that just has the project MyFramework in it, but MyPlugin.dll is in the bin/Modules folder.  When I instantiate a catalog using

```
string Path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin");
string ModulesPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin/Modules");
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(
    new DirectoryCatalog(Path)
    new DirectoryCatalog(ModulesPath)
);
```

I can see that the assembly for MyPlugin.dll is loaded, but no Parts are found.  I tried using MEFx to dump composition state as described [here](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Debugging%20and%20Diagnostics&referringTitle=Guide) like so:

```
string Path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin");
string ModulesPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin/Modules");
var binCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path);
var modulesCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(ModulesPath);
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(binCatalog, modulesCatalog);

using (var container = new CompositionContainer(modulesCatalog))
{
    var ci = new CompositionInfo(modulesCatalog, container);
    var stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    CompositionInfoTextFormatter.Write(ci, stringWriter);
    string compositionStateString = stringWriter.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

but compositionStateString is just an empty string.

I'm having trouble understanding where the issue is coming from.  Since MyFramework has no direct reference to MyPlugin, it shouldn't matter if the two projects are compiled as part of the same solution, right?

Additional info:
I have bin/Modules in the [probing path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806467/how-can-i-set-privatebinpath-in-mef?rq=1).

I'm exporting controllers by decorating them with a custom export attribute:

```
[ExportModuleControllerAttribute("NotificationsController")]
public class NotificationsController : BaseController
{
    //...
}
```

That attribute is defined in MyFramework like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class), MetadataAttribute]
public class ExportModuleControllerAttribute : ExportAttribute, INamedMetadata        
{
    public string[] Dependencies { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ExportModuleControllerAttribute(string name, params string[] dependencies)
        : base(typeof(IController))
    {
        Dependencies = dependencies;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

As is the INamedMetadata interface:

```
public interface INamedMetadata
{
    #region Properties
    string Name { get; }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Peter makes some good points.  I'd also recommend that you try Visual MEFX.  You can find it in the `mefcontrib-tools` project.  This will let you interactively explore your assemblies.  You can add them one at a time and see if there is anything exported.

Here's an article on getting it setup: [Getting Started with Visual MEFX](http://ihadthisideaonce.com/2012/02/22/getting-started-with-visual-mefx/)

Comment: When I load MyPlugin.dll into Visual MEFX nothing happens.  I assume that is supposed to mean that there are no exports in that dll, though that could be made clearer.  Maybe I'm exporting incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, in my experience, Visual MEFX does nothing when an Assembly has no exports.  Its would try simplifying the way you declare your exports.  Start by using an ordinary Export attribute with no meta data, see if it shows up.  Then try adding some metadata and see if that works.  Hopefully after a few iterations you can pinpoint exactly whats wrong.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out the issue yet since work priorities have me working on other projects, but this answer has me pointed in the right direction.  Thanks Jim.

Answer (score 3):

How are you exporting classes (I'm guessing Controllers) etc in your module dlls? lets see some more code. It's not enough to setup a catalog you actually have to tell mef to put things in it.

Also do a count on ci.PartDefinitions to see if you have anything in there. In fact inspect the ci and the container variables in the debugger and see what you have got in them.

Also why are you only inspecting modulesCatalog shouldn't you be inspecting catalog eg

```
 var ci = new CompositionInfo(catalog, container);
```

Anyhow hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I've edited the question above to add the exporting code.  In my actual code I'm inspecting catalog but I thought it would make it clearer that the issue was with the modulesCatalog since that's the catalog that isn't loading Parts correctly.  If I inspect catalog I get the same output I would get if I only inspected binCatalog.  

Using catalog to create the CompositionInfo, `ci.PartDefinitions.Count()` returns 4 when it should return 8.  I inspected ci in the debugger but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for besides the Parts that aren't there.

Comment: Try putting you modules in different dirctory like app_code also turn off the probing path stuff. Also try exporting with the standard Exportattribute not the custom one if you want metadata with your exports MEf has a Metadata attribute for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have included your `*.pdb` files in the startup bin folder.

`*.dll` is not sufficient to satisfy imports.